# Replace mcrypt MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256 with openssl or change it to AES

Tags: c#, php, encryption, openssl

I'm building a simple PHP script that need to decode input from C# application.
I've created C# app with below encrypting function (I've also included my decrypting function):

```
public static string Encrypt(string input, string key)
{
    var aes = new RijndaelManaged
    {
        KeySize = 256,
        BlockSize = 256,
        Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7,
        Mode = CipherMode.CBC,
        Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key) 
    };

    aes.GenerateIV();
    var encryptor = aes.CreateEncryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV);
    byte[] buffer;
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
            byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);
            cs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }
        buffer = ms.ToArray();
    }
    buffer = buffer.Concat(aes.IV).ToArray();
    return Convert.ToBase64String(buffer);
}

private static String Decrypt(string text, string key)
{
    RijndaelManaged aes = new RijndaelManaged
    {
        KeySize = 256,
        BlockSize = 256,
        Mode = CipherMode.CBC,
        Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7,
        Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key)
    };

    byte[] encoded = Convert.FromBase64String(text);
    byte[] buffer = encoded.Take(encoded.Length - aes.IV.Length).ToArray();
    aes.IV = encoded.Skip(encoded.Length - aes.IV.Length).ToArray();
    var decrypt = aes.CreateDecryptor();
    byte[] xBuff;
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, decrypt, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
            cs.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        }
        xBuff = ms.ToArray();
    }
    var output = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(xBuff);
    return output;
}
```

After couple of minutes of searching I've found simple decryption function in PHP using mcrypt:

```
function strippadding($string)
{
    $slast = ord(substr($string, -1));
    $slastc = chr($slast);
    $pcheck = substr($string, -$slast);
    if(preg_match("/$slastc{".$slast."}/", $string)){
    $string = substr($string, 0, strlen($string)-$slast);
        return $string;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

function decrypt($string, $key)
{
    $string = base64_decode($string);
    $iv = substr($string, -32);
    $string = str_replace($iv, "", $string);
    return strippadding(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $string, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv));
}
```

This works well, but as I read on multiple sites, mcrypt is no longer recommended and sooner or later will be removed.

I'm trying to recreate same function using openssl, but without any luck.
I've tried replacing `mcrypt_decrypt` with:

```
openssl_decrypt($string, 'aes-256-cbc', $encryption_key, 0, $iv);
```

but as I found out [MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256 doesn't mean AES-256.](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/05/if-you-re-typing-word-mcrypt-into-your-code-you-re-doing-it-wrong)
I've been trying with different key size and block size, but without luck.

How can I recreate PHP decrypting function using openssl?

**EDIT1 :**

I've changed `RijndaelManaged` with `AesCryptoServiceProvider` in my C# code:

```
var aes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider()
{
    KeySize = 256,
    BlockSize = 128,
    Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7,
    Mode = CipherMode.CBC,
    Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key) 
};
```

and inside PHP to:

```
define('AES_128_CBC', 'aes-128-cbc');

function decrypt_openssl($string, $pkey)
{
    $key = $pkey;
    $string = base64_decode($string);
    $iv = substr($string, -32);
    $string = str_replace($iv, "", $string);

    $decrypted = openssl_decrypt($string, AES_128_CBC, base64_encode($key), 0, base64_encode($iv));
    return $decrypted;
}
```

but still I can't get encoded string to be decoded in PHP.

I need a way to decrypt output of my C# function or change both to get that two way communication working.

**EDIT2:**

I'm providing full source of my C# class:

```
public static string EncryptRijndael(string input, string key)
{
    var aes = new RijndaelManaged
    {
        KeySize = 256,
        BlockSize = 256,
        Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7,
        Mode = CipherMode.CBC,
        Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key)
    };

    aes.GenerateIV();

    var encryptor = aes.CreateEncryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV);

    byte[] buffer;
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
            byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);
            cs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }
        buffer = ms.ToArray();
    }

    buffer = buffer.Concat(aes.IV).ToArray();

    aes.Dispose();
    return Convert.ToBase64String(buffer);
}

public static string DecryptRijndael(string input, string key)
{
    var aes = new RijndaelManaged
    {
        KeySize = 256,
        BlockSize = 256,
        Mode = CipherMode.CBC,
        Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7,
        Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key)
    };

    byte[] xXml = Convert.FromBase64String(input);
    var buffer = xXml.Take(xXml.Length - aes.IV.Length).ToArray();
    var iv = xXml.Skip(xXml.Length - aes.IV.Length).ToArray();

    aes.IV = iv;
    var decrypt = aes.CreateDecryptor();
    byte[] xBuff;
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, decrypt, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
            cs.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        }
        xBuff = ms.ToArray();
    }
    aes.Dispose();
    String output = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(xBuff);
    return output;
}


public static string EncryptAes(string input, string key)
{
    var aes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider()
    {
        KeySize = 256,
        BlockSize = 128,
        Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7,
        Mode = CipherMode.CBC,
        Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key) 
    };

    aes.GenerateIV();
    var encryptor = aes.CreateEncryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV);
    byte[] buffer;
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
            byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);
            cs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }
        buffer = ms.ToArray();
    }

    buffer = buffer.Concat(aes.IV).ToArray();
    aes.Dispose();
    return Convert.ToBase64String(buffer);
}

public static String DecryptAes(string input, string key)
{
    var aes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider()
    {
        KeySize = 256,
        BlockSize = 128,
        Mode = CipherMode.CBC,
        Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7,
        Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key) 
    };

    byte[] xXml = Convert.FromBase64String(input);
    var buffer = xXml.Take(xXml.Length - aes.IV.Length).ToArray();
    var iv = xXml.Skip(xXml.Length - aes.IV.Length).ToArray();

    aes.IV = iv;
    var decrypt = aes.CreateDecryptor();
    byte[] xBuff;
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, decrypt, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
            cs.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        }
        xBuff = ms.ToArray();
    }
    aes.Dispose();
    String output = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(xBuff);
    return output;
}
```

My test key is: `zjPUcCp9Jn7k8RtEzxTRePjn984LqwyN`
My test data as plain text: `zażółć geślą jaźń`
My test data as base64: `emHFvMOzxYLEhyBnZcWbbMSFIGphxbrFhA==`
And sample output for both encryption functions:
**Rijndael**: 4gD/tt3I3hqYToLnwxI/HJ37EHfXrd1uxchIOjuxSuZl0Kyvxb+S6h4gG3cWKJTbj0wDSH1zvbeSvHd9Wu1VaA==
**AES**: B0dKdL4k9J6CeqlAekaXM+eh/zDqd5B4sKK2p6DFsgYNbV56Xdy01XvYPZX8ZXBc

IV is added at the end of byte array just before creating base64 output. When decrypting I'm reading IV from end of input string and using it to decrypt.

I need to ensure I can encrypt/decrypt utf-8 strings.

Comment: Rijndael with a block size of 16-bytes and a key size of 128, 192 or 256 bits is AES. PHP mcrypt is a problem, it does not support standard PKCS#7 (née PKCS#5) padding, only non-standard null padding.

Comment: @zaph I'm not PHP developer, so if You could please show how to modify my code. As I correctly understand I must set that in PHP? Or do I must change C# part?

Comment: It is best not to use mcrypt, it has been abandonware for nearly a decade now. It has therefore been deprecated and will be removed from the core and into PECL in PHP 7.2. It does not support standard PKCS#7 (née PKCS#5) padding, only non-standard null padding that can't even be used with binary data. mcrypt has many outstanding bugs dating back to 2003. Instead consider using [defuse](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption) or [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor), they provide a complete solution, are being maintained and is correct.

Comment: @zaph I must agree that mcrypt is no way to go, that's why I want to use openssl and it that's possible I'd like to avoid any external libraries. In C# part I'm using CBC Mode with PKCS7 padding.

Comment: @zaph I can change C# part it that would make it more easy to decrypt on PHP site.

Comment: @zaph do You mean C# part? I've tried changing BlockSize to 128, but I can't decrypt that in PHP. I've also tried changing KeySize to 128, but that also didn't help

Comment: @zaph I've tried that. I've changed that in C# and set `aes-128-cbc` in PHP, but I don't get result in PHP.

Comment: @zaph I'm using same key - 32 characters, padding is set to PKCS7 and I'm using UTF-8 in C# and in PHP

Comment: @zaph test data contains Polish letters, that's why it's not clear. I've used those letters because I want to be sure they are correctly encrypted/decrypted in both languages (C# and PHP). When using mcrypt this works fine. Sorry for not making this clear at start.

Comment: @zaph "zażółć geślą jaźń" is input string that I'm passing to my encrypt function, result is base64 encoded value that is encrypted. I can then pass that encrypted value to my decrypt function and after decryption I get same input string - "zażółć geślą jaźń". I've tried that with RijndaelManaged and AES in C# and this works fine. I'm not security specialist, but after encrypting and decrypting I get same value, so for me this works fine. If not please correct me.

Comment: Why that down vote? At least add reason so I can ask better question next time.

Comment: @zaph in my question I've written that `zjPUcCp9Jn7k8RtEzxTRePjn984LqwyN` is my key and `zażółć geślą jaźń` is my test data - string that I'm encoding. Please take a look. inside EDIT 2 just below my code.

Comment: My error. Don't test with multiple variables: string encoding and encryption libraries/languages, test one at a time.

Comment: @zaph I've tested that with C# and it works fine, in both direction. I'm able to encode/decode. As I wrote in my question my problem is to replace mcrypt with openssl in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer but added as an answer because of necessary formatting and length:

Provided by the OP:

Encryption input:
test key is: `zjPUcCp9Jn7k8RtEzxTRePjn984LqwyN`
test data as plain text: `zażółć geślą jaźń` (not used, see below)
test data as base64: `emHFvMOzxYLEhyBnZcWbbMSFIGphxbrFhA==` (used)
Sample output for both encryption functions:
Rijndael: `4gD/tt3I3hqYToLnwxI/HJ37EHfXrd1uxchIOjuxSuZl0Kyvxb+S6h4gG3cWKJTbj0wDSH1zvbeSvHd9Wu1VaA==`
AES: `B0dKdL4k9J6CeqlAekaXM+eh/zDqd5B4sKK2p6DFsgYNbV56Xdy01XvYPZX8ZXBc`

Provided data displayed as hex for consistency, spaces added for legibility:

RijndaelExpected:  `e200ffb6 ddc8de1a 984e82e7 c3123f1c 9dfb1077 d7addd6e c5c8483a 3bb14ae6 65d0acaf c5bf92ea 1e201b77 162894db 8f4c0348 7d73bdb7 92bc777d 5aed5568`
AESExpected:  `07474a74 be24f49e 827aa940 7a469733 e7a1ff30 ea779078 b0a2b6a7 a0c5b206 0d6d5e7a 5ddcb4d5 7bd83d95 fc65705c`

testData:  `7a61c5bc c3b3c582 c4872067 65c59b6c c485206a 61c5bac5 84`
testKey:   `7a6a5055 63437039 4a6e376b 38527445 7a785452 65506a6e 3938344c 7177794e`
testIV:    `8f4c0348 7d73bdb7 92bc777d 5aed5568` (from RijndaelExpected trailing bytes).

The above is what one would hope for in a question.

Assumptions: PKCS#7 padding, CBC mode.
Based on the data 7-bytes of padding is expected so the encrypted data should be 32-bytes.

The RijndaelExpected output is 64-bytes, minus 16-bytes for the appended IV is 48-bytes which is incorrect.

The AESExpected output is 48-bytes. If the IV is appended it does not match RijndaelExpected, it the IV is not appended it is the wrong length.

My calculated AES output without an appended IV is (Note an IV generally prefixes the encrypted data):

CryptData: `1a6ec05d 00a6e61b 8196e7f2 879e2f59 25d3b7e2 c103f7e6 41c8c93f 70b32de5`
Which does not agree with either expected output.

Also see this [online AES calculator](http://extranet.cryptomathic.com/aescalc?key=7a6a5055634370394a6e376b385274457a78545265506a6e3938344c7177794e&iv=8f4c03487d73bdb792bc777d5aed5568&input=7a61c5bcc3b3c582c487206765c59b6cc485206a61c5bac58407070707070707&mode=cbc&action=Encrypt&output=)  Note that PKCS#7 padding has been manually added.

For completness only, my test code:

```
NSData *testData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:@"emHFvMOzxYLEhyBnZcWbbMSFIGphxbrFhA==" options:0];
NSData *testKey  = [@"zjPUcCp9Jn7k8RtEzxTRePjn984LqwyN" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSData *testIV   = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:@"j0wDSH1zvbeSvHd9Wu1VaA==" options:0];

size_t movedBytes = 0;
NSMutableData *cryptData = [NSMutableData dataWithLength: testData.length + kCCBlockSizeAES128];
CCCrypt(kCCEncrypt, kCCAlgorithmAES128,
        kCCOptionPKCS7Padding, // CBC  mode is the default
        testKey.bytes, kCCKeySizeAES256,
        testIV.bytes,
        testData.bytes, testData.length,
        cryptData.mutableBytes, cryptData.length,
        &movedBytes);
cryptData.length = movedBytes;
Display(@"CryptData: %@", cryptData);
```